# accumulate numpy array for just one column

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array, i want to accumulate the values of one column, say the 2<sup>nd</sup> column.

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[2,4]])
# some kind of accumulate function that accumulates just one column:
np.add.accumulate(a, 2)
```

`a` should now be `[[1,2],[2,6]]`

Is there a way to do this in NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[2,4]])
np.add.accumulate(a[:,1], out=a[:,1])
```

`a` is now:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 6]])
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `a[:,1].cumsum(out=a[:,1])`.