# How to accumulate values in numpy array by column?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I use the numpy [accumulator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html#numpy.ufunc.accumulate) and [add](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.add.html#numpy.add) functions to add arrays column wise to make a basic accumulator?

```
   import numpy as np
   a = np.array([1,1,1])
   b = np.array([2,2,2])
   c = np.array([3,3,3])
   two_dim = np.array([a,b,c])
   y = np.array([0,0,0])
   for x in two_dim:
     y = np.add.accumulate(x,axis=0,out=y)                               
     return y
```

actual output: `[1,2,3]`
desired output: `[6,6,6]`

numpy glossary says the [sum along axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/glossary.html#term-along-an-axis) argument `axis=1` sums over rows: *"we can sum each row of an array, in which case we operate along columns, or axis 1".*

*"A 2-dimensional array has two corresponding axes: the first running vertically downwards across rows (axis 0), and the second running horizontally across columns (axis 1)"*

With `axis=1` I would expect output `[3,6,9]`, but this also returns `[1,2,3]`.

**Of Course!** neither x nor y are two-dimensional.

What am I doing wrong?

I can manually use `np.add()`

```
aa = np.array([1,1,1])
bb = np.array([2,2,2])
cc = np.array([3,3,3])
yy = np.array([0,0,0])
l = np.add(aa,yy)
m = np.add(bb,l)
n = np.add(cc,m)
print n
```

and now I get the correct output, `[6,6,6]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

```
two_dim.sum(axis=0)
# [6 6 6]
```

will give you what you want.

I don't think `accumulate` is what you're looking for as it provides a running operation, so, using `add` it would look like:

```
np.add.accumulate(two_dim)

[[1 1 1]
 [3 3 3]    # = 1+2
 [6 6 6]]   # = 1+2+3
```

`reduce` is more like what you've descibed:

```
np.add.reduce(two_dim)

[6 6 6]
```

Comment: LOL. Reading example with [np.accumulate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176968/accumulate-numpy-array-for-just-one-column) I thought a numpy func would be the way to go. I'm humbled.

Comment: Actually, I would like to have the running total in the array. I will _try_ to read the docs to see which is best. tx.

Comment: @xtian: Just to be clear, `sum` as used here is the numpy version and not the python version.  If you want the running totals, you could use `add.accumulate` or the cumulative sum `cumsum`, they're equivalent (at least in output).